# Avoid auto hide when moving between windows using VIM split horizontal

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I am struggling with this odd behavior. I am learning vim and I guess I deconfigure it trying to playing with multiple windows.

Now when I split horizontally a window (using ***ctrl+ws***) and try to move between them, I can only see a window at the same time (I guess the size of the focused window is set to 100% automatically) so I can re-size it again using ***ctrl+w=***, but it's frustating do it many times.

UPDATE:

I am using the [spf13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc) config. And using this my local config in [.vimrc.local](https://gist.github.com/oskargicast/7e69bfedd6ecd57eb9bc)

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `:set winheight=999`, this creates this effect.

Find out where it got set via

```
:verbose set winheight?
```

and remove that setting, or undo it via `:set winheight&`.

Comment: I love that "rolodex" effect.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my winheight is set to 1. I did *:set winheight&* and still having the same behavior :(

Comment: Then you need to tell us more about your config; can you post a link to your .vimrc? Is the `<C-w>s` command mapped?

Comment: I am using the [spf13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc) config. And using this local config in [.vimrc.local](https://gist.github.com/oskargicast/7e69bfedd6ecd57eb9bc)

Comment: I don't think that's the default behavior of spf13, but you could open an issue there to request support. Vim "distributions" like _spf-13_ and _Janus_ lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks @IngoKarkat, I realized I was moving inside splits using **ctrl + [hjkl]** (this works with vertical splits). The right should be **ctrl-w + [hjkl]** ... I'm a vim newbie.

Comment: And those mappings come from your distribution... I hope you'll understand my concerns now. Anyway, I'm glad you've found the cause!

Comment: Yup. I found that mapping [here](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc#L250). And I can acomplish the behavior that I was looking for with [this](https://gist.github.com/oskargicast/7e69bfedd6ecd57eb9bc). Thanks for the advice anyway :)